# What's behind the Banach-Tarski paradox?

Tags: geometry, big-list, philosophy, foundations, paradoxes

The discovery of [the Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) was of course a great thing in mathematics but raises the issue of the relation between mathematics and reality. Empirically there are good reasons for faith in mathematical proofs: well derived mathematical theories and formulas, used in an accurate manner in science, really bring observable results. I don't know any scientific failures where mathematical results was blamed.

Naturally constructive proofs are preferable but there shouldn't be any problem with [non-constructive proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof#Non-constructive_proofs): the mathematical-logical machinery should guaranty the expected success. With or without the use of the law of the excluded middle!

So how to explain the non-intuitive theorem of Banach-Tarski? Which are the "weak pillars" or combinations of them? Personally I can't see the axiom of choice as a problem, since it only is a condition of what's to be called a set. Is the theorem perhaps a sign of lack of continuity in reality?

> I really would like a big list of suggestions what "axioms" could be
>   changed to avoid the "possibility" of the the theorem.

---

I have been re-considering. Suppose that a new discrete theory about space and time was developed and was found to be consistent with observations. How long would it take before a corresponding theory was developed from a pure geometrical perspective? Compare with the corresponding theories of Heisenberg and Schrödinger!

What was explained in one way in the discrete theory maybe was described in a totally differnt way in the continuous theory? And who knows, maybe similar constructions as in the paradoxes of Banach-Tarski and Sierpinski-Mazurkiewicz, would be used to explain the expansion of what is now called dark energy? And even "worse", to explain the result of high energy proton- proton collisions?

It strikes me that the relative terms of consistency as is used in mathematics is all what is needed for the mathematical material to be used in scientific theories. Physicists do sometimes use mathematics in extraordinary ways and get good results.

But that does not make it less interesting to ponder the pillars of the "paradoxes".

Also, thanks for reopen and for great answers!

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, what do you mean by "how to explain the non-intuitive theorem"? There are many theorems in mathematics which appear to be unintuitive (like existence of nowhere differentiable continuous functions), this only shows how limited our intuition is and says nothing about "weak pillars", whatever this means.

Comment: @studiosus: yes, perhaps I should have been written counter-intuitive instead? But will the theorem ever be applicable to anything real? The geometry is supposed to model reality.

Comment: @Lehs Not sure what you've been reading, but the theorem is not attempting to model anything physical at all.

Comment: @Lehs Have you met ordinals and cardinals? Do you think $\aleph_\omega$ represents anything real?

Comment: @Lac: no, the theorem is not a model of anything, but the geometry in which the theorem is formulated, really is supposed to model space.

Comment: @user2345215: Ordinals and cardinals is set theory which is not a model of reality as such but perhaps of human mind and psychology?

Comment: @Lehs This question is either a duplicate or an unclear question. As such, I've voted to close it. [See this very similar question on the Math Educators Stack Exchange whose answers will probably help you.](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/what-do-you-say-to-students-who-want-to-apply-banach-tarski-theorem-in-practice).

Comment: Whenever you see a paradox, look at your assumption. The assumption that non-measurable sets behave anything like our intuition of geometric objects is the fault here. Banach/Tarski is sort of three-dimensional case of that intuition failure. In the end, I still find it irritating a little that the rationals can be covered by intervals whose total length ads of to less than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$. I know it is true, by proving it, but that doesn't mean I like it. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: but could the Banach-Tarski trick ever occur in nature?

Comment: Lech: I think, your question stems from the mistaken belief that "The geometry is supposed to model reality". Voting to close.

Comment: I know nothing about nature, Lehs, except that mathematics only seems to ever approximate it. :) @Lehs

Comment: @studiosus: So geometry isn't a model of space?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: thanks for the link!

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Yes, but that is the big challenge for me, to understand why math&science approximate nature so well.

Comment: I've never seen anybody referencing anything like a real world analogy to BT. Who knows, maybe when we measure the matter in the universe that we can see, we are measuring thr inner measure of a set, and the outer measure gives us the visibile and "dark matter." :)

Comment: @Lechs: It is even worse: There is no such thing as "geometry", there are many different geometries, some model space, some model time, some model spacetime, some model other obscure things (like information, or stock market), some model nothing at all.

Comment: The proof is actually wrong. By carefully selecting the test we can verify the decomposition and reassembly lost surface density. I discovered by accident a property that allows for computation of the measure of the sum of unmeasurable sets (sum is a really odd concept but behaves like union if the sets are disjoint) and can demonstrate conservation across affine transforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a splitting of the Banach-Tarski theorem into a constructive and a nonconstructive part.

The first, which as von Neumann showed is the principle behind many similar problems, is the existence of a noncommutative free group $F$ inside the group of congruences of 3-dimensional space.  The proof that such a group exists does not use the axiom of choice, and is the hard part of the proof that uses "real math facts".

The second, nonconstructive part is to take a cross-section of the quotient by the action of a (2-generator subgroup of) $F$ so as to get the pieces of the decomposition.  This uses the axiom of choice, is probably equivalent to AC or a slightly weaker uncountable choice principle, and is a clever, but easier and more formal part of the argument.

What would survive without axiom of choice or the like are the proofs that the Euclidean isometry (or rotation, volume-preserving, etc symmetry) groups contain pairs of elements generating a free subgroup.  That would no longer imply a paradoxical decomposition into congruent pieces, but it is also possible that the nonconstructive theory can be adapted in some way to get analogous restriction on the existence of congruence-invariant measures from the existence of the free subgroup.  For example, if you allow closures of the pieces and not only congruent copies, then no AC is needed to get a decomposition:

http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1994-07-01/S0894-0347-1994-1227475-8/S0894-0347-1994-1227475-8.pdf

> We also prove related "paradoxes" which ... are entirely constructive and make no use of the Axiom of Choice.  ... one can find a finite collection of disjoint open subsets of the unit ball which can be rearranged by suitable isometries to form a set whose closure is a solid ball of radius 10^10  [Dougherty and Foreman, *Banach-Tarski Decompositions Using Sets with the Property of Baire*]

Comment: I'm not sure as to what you're trying to suggest is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: Existence of a section from (sphere modulo group action) to (sphere).   It requires more than countable dependent choice, DC, since from the section there is a construction of nonmeasurable sets.  And it probably implies some uncountable version of AC for sets of reals.  Maybe you know some more precise consequences?

Comment: Not really. I can tell you that the BT theorem is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem, which itself is a consequence of the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem, which is consistent with the existence of an infinite Dedekind-finite set of reals. So in terms of "such and such families have choice functions", I'm not sure that this is really equivalent to a reasonable statement.

Answer (score 24):

If anything, the non-reality of the Banach-Tarski decomposition is because the sets the theorem speaks about *lack* continuity that reality does have. Even though the theorem divides the sphere into a finite number of "pieces", those pieces cannot exist as physical objects; the points inside and outside of the set are too finely intermingled to make it reasonable to cut it out physically from a continuum.

However, we don't need to go to Banach-Tarski, or even to the Axiom of Choice or non-constructiveness in order to see this situation.

For example, consider a cube in $\mathbb R^3$ and divide it into two pieces: one that consists of points with at least one rational coordinate, and another one consisting of those points that have all coordinates irrational.

These "pieces" are just as unphysical as the pieces in the Banach-Tarski decomposition, but defining what they are requires no mathematically questionable foundational assumptions at all. They don't seem "as paradoxical" as the Banach-Tarski pieces, because they happen to be Lebesgue measurable -- but that just tell us that simply being measurable doesn't mean that a set of points is *physically* meaningful.

Comment: Yes, but neither continuity or lack of continuity is a problem in math. If there is no real continuity however, then there are irreparable deficiencies with continuous models.

Comment: @Lehs: As for physical reality, actual physical objects are made of atoms and so fundamentally not continuous. This doesn't prevent continuous models from being _useful_ for analyzing a wide range of situations.

Comment: Yes for atomic matter, but what about the mysterious black energy..? And yes, continuous models are very useful.

Comment: "the *lack* continuity that reality does have". I think it's pretty difficult to judge about the properties of reality.

Comment: @NikolajK: that's what happens when we mix up models and _reality_... and by the way, I am not sure everybody agrees on a definition of _reality_. Personally, I prefer to stick to _models_ and _measurements_, and leave _reality_, _explanations_ etc. to non-scientists. Oh, and by the way, I never observed a right angle in nature, does it exist in _reality_ ? :D

Answer (score 15):

There is an implicit axiom that people assume

> sets of points in the plane should be meaningful geometrically

This, of course, isn't an axiom of ZFC or of real analysis; this is an implicit expectation of people who want to apply set theory to geometric problems.

Measure theory, one of the more general and powerful tools for defining contexts where we can "measure" things, gives us the phrase "measurable set", and the tools of measure theory only really apply to measurable sets.

Of course, most things you do are measurable. People want to go so far as to think of the adjective "measurable" as being a mere technicality that one doesn't really have to pay attention to.

Of course, problems with this axiom were already known prior to the discovery of the Banach-Tarski paradox. However, they were weird and complicated, so people don't feel so strongly about this axiom failing.

There's sort of a metaprinciple that if you start with something reasonable, end with something reasonable, and do reasonable things inbetween, the result should be meaningful. The axiom people really want to assume is

> reasonable sets of points in the plane treated reasonably in a way that produces reasonable results should tell us something meaningful

And to be fair, this isn't a terrible thing to want to assume; it means we can ignore a lot of technicalities if things don't smell wrong. And, in fact, a huge amount of calculus just works under these conditions; there are a lot of theorems that support the above axiom in a wide variety of situations.

The Banach-Tarski paradox, however, closes the rest of the loopholes. A ball is a reasonable set. Two balls are a reasonable set. Splitting a ball into finitely many pieces is reasonable. Moving sets around with Euclidean motions is reasonable.

The *only* weird thing is that the individual pieces are non-measurable.

The fact that we did everything reasonably except for that one technical condition and failed to get a reasonable result appears to irk people quite a lot. It drives home the point that if you want to use measures, you to actually need to know whether the things you're doing result in measurable sets.

Now, as for the specific question you asked, the only axioms we need to get rid of are the two blockquoted axioms I stated above. They were never axioms of mathematics anyways, so from that perspective we're already done!

Sure, it's technically still a theorem of mathematics, but we were interested in *measuring things*, and it's not a theorem about *measurable sets*, so since we're supposed to talk about *measurable sets*, the theorem isn't relevant to us and there's nothing to be worried about.

(naturally, there are people who are more vested in their implicit axioms rather than the convenience that the axiom of choice gives us, thus rejecting the axiom of choice in favor of adopting the axiom that all subsets of the real numbers are measurable)

---

And a bonus joke: what's an anagram of Banach-Tarski?

> Banach-Tarski Banach-Tarski

Comment: @MattR. You must only upvote a post if you think it answers the question or adds something useful to an answer. A joke does none of these.

Comment: @mathh This is a good answer with many interesting points. My earlier comment was a flip way of saying "I appreciate the cherry on top of this ice-cream sundae".

Comment: +1 because I can upvote for any reason I feel like?

Comment: As I keep pointing out, rejecting choice and taking up "all sets are measurable" implies that you can partition the reals into more non-empty parts than points. If that is not paradoxical, I don't know what is...

Comment: Banach,Tarski, I Summon Ye! please duplicate my upvote on this answer!!!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Don't worry, I personally agree with you that this is shockingly paradoxical. Can you point us to a reference to this fact? (I am wanting to put my brain into a blender, but this seems an adequate substitute ;-P)

Comment: @Matemáticos Chibchas: It was shown by Sierpinski (if my memory serves me right at this time of night) that if there is a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $[\Bbb R]^\omega$ (the set of all countably infinite subsets of $\Bbb R$), then there is a non-measurable set. Note that there is always an injection from $\Bbb R$ into that set, and there is always a surjection from $\Bbb R$ onto that set. So if all sets are measurable, we can partition $\Bbb R$ into $|[\Bbb R]^\omega|$ different, non-empty parts, which is strictly more than $|\Bbb R|$. Simply fix such a surjection, and look at its fibers.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that the axiom at fault is the axiom of infinity. The physical world deals only with finite sets, which is why we never encounter these paradoxical decompositions in practice; they come up automatically any time infinite sets are involved.

Almost by definition, an infinite set is one which is equal in size to a proper subset. Geometrically speaking, you can translate the set of natural numbers by one unit and obtain the exact same set, but leaving out one point. As mathematicians we often take this for granted, but this should already get your common-sense-warning-bells ringing - you can just pick something up, move it, and have it fit inside itself with room to spare!

Ok, but that's a set that "runs off to infinity," so as long as we restrict to bounded sets we're fine, right? Nope, you can wrap a copy of the natural numbers around a circle (rotating by an irrational multiple of pi each time), and simply by rotating this set, you again get a copy of this set but with points removed. No axiom of choice involved.

Ok, but all these examples aren't as bad as Banach-Tarski, you may say - yes, you get a set which is congruent to a proper subset, but you can't split a set into two copies the same size as the original.

Well lo and behold, the deep dark secret of paradoxical decompositions: A set in the plane which is congruent (note: not just equidecomposable, actually *congruent*) to two disjoint copies of itself. And it's a set that you can explicitly define. No axiom of choice necessary. [The Sierpinski-Mazurkiewicz paradox](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/30001.1-2-8.shtml).

The only difference between this paradoxical decomposition and the Banach-Tarski paradox is that this one doesn't break our intuition of measure (the sets involved are measure zero). But the proof of Banach-Tarski actually starts off almost identically to this one; the paradox comes from an *algebraic* construction (essentially, the meat of the Banach-Tarski paradox is that the free group on two generators embeds into the group of rotations of a sphere). The only problem is that this construction gives a measure zero subset of the sphere. The axiom of choice simply allows you to "flesh out" the paradoxical pieces you found to cover the whole ball. Its role is that of a bridge from zero measure to positive measure (which is why it's so useful in analysis and we should most definitely not get rid of it); the paradox itself comes from algebra. And all this algebraic construction needs is for infinite sets to exist.

Though it feels really campy to end with a Wikipedia quote, I feel their article on [paradoxical sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxical_set) says it best: "Paradoxical sets exist as a consequence of the Axiom of Infinity. Admitting infinite classes as sets is sufficient to allow paradoxical sets."

Comment: Re: "The only difference between this paradoxical decomposition and the Banach-Tarski paradox is that this one doesn't break our intuition of measure (the sets involved are measure zero)": Well, that, but also that this one deals with *unbounded* sets. (Whereas Banach-Tarksi deals with solid balls.) So while the Sierpinski-Mazurkiewicz paradox is a particularly cool construction, it's not really any more counterintuitive than Hilbert's paradox of the Grand Hotel.

Comment: @ruakh This is true, but the example I gave of going from the natural numbers to the circle is significant - we know there are instances of a phenomenon that works for unbounded sets being "wrapped around itself" to work for bounded sets as well. Of course, this doesn't mean that it will automatically work in this case as well, but it turns out that the paradoxical sets used in the Banach-Tarski paradox are essentially the same as those used in Sierpinski-Mazurkiewicz, just wrapped up around the sphere (the only difference is that one uses a free monoid and the other uses a free group)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. O.K., I'm convinced. +1. :-)

Comment: Yay thanks! You do raise a good point though, and it's something I didn't really state clearly in my post, so thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: The physical world doesn't deal with sets at all!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Maybe more precisely, not the assumption of the existence of uncountable sets, but allowing the existence of uncountable sets is one of the issues. In our universe/reality there are finitely-many atoms ( someone around here may have a good estimate of the total amount), which do not allow for the constructions in Banach-Tarski.

Comment: Not to mention the space and time itself may be quantized.

Comment: Hm, I had not thought of that, good point. Maybe you can write it as an answer.

Comment: The main "problem" (if it is a problem) is the axiom of choice, not the axiom of power set (the axiom of power set implies the existence of uncountably infinite sets).

Comment: I am not referring to the underlying axioms, I am referring to the conclusion, which may follow from many different (sets of ) axioms.

Comment: OK, let me edit, maybe my way of phrasing things was ambiguous.

Comment: Still, you are arguing incorrectly: just because there are uncountable sets does not imply that the existence of these sets follows from a specific axiom.