# Non-measurable set from bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

In the comments to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1078403/284973) there are a few statements that interest me which I would like some clarification on. Apologies if the material referred to has been asked about here before. [Asaf Karagila](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila) makes the comment:

> As I keep pointing out, rejecting choice and taking up "all sets are measurable" implies that you can partition the reals into more non-empty parts than points. If that is not paradoxical, I don't know what is...

and then explains this in a later comment as follows:

> It was shown by Sierpinski (if my memory serves me right at this time of night) that if there is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$ (the set of all countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$), then there is a non-measurable set. Note that there is always an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ into that set, and there is always a surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ onto that set. So if all sets are measurable, we can partition $\mathbb{R}$ into $|[\mathbb{R}]^\omega|$ different, non-empty parts, which is strictly more than $|\mathbb{R}|$. Simply fix such a surjection, and look at its fibers.

I do not know the source of the theorem of [Sierpinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wac%C5%82aw_Sierpi%C5%84ski) referred to here, and I would love it if someone could point me towards it. I think I understand the rest of the argument; I assume since an [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) (e.g. map each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ to its [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics))?) and [surjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) can exist without a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) that [Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) is being rejected here; I think I get why we can [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) $\mathbb{R}$ into $|[\mathbb{R}]^\omega|$ parts if there is a surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$ (for each element in $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$ we find the corresponding [fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(mathematics)) of the surjection), and I see why $|[\mathbb{R}]^\omega|>|\mathbb{R}|$ (since there is an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ into $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$ without a bijection; please correct my reasoning if it wrong). However, I don't quite see why the surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$ must exist.

Thus I have the following questions: Could anyone point me to the theorem of Sierpinski (perhaps) referred to here, and could anyone point out why the surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$ must exist?

Comment: The Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem says that, if there is an ***INJECTION*** from $A$ to $B$ and an ***INJECTION*** from $B$ to $A,$ then there is a bijection between $A$ and $B.$ The theorem does not apply when you have an injection and a ***SURJECTION*** from $A$ to $B.$

Comment: For instance, if $A=\mathbb R$ and $B=\mathbb R\cup\omega_1,$ then (without the axiom of choice) you have an injection from $A$ to $B,$ and a surjection from $A$ to $B,$ and a surjection from $B$ to $A,$ but you need the axiom of choice to get a bijection from $A$ to $B.$ The Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem is no help here.

Comment: @bof True that. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^\omega$ are equipotent. Now map every sequence to its image (add the rationals if that image is finite).

You can find a discussion with citation and proof in [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/191262/7206).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but there's something I'm not getting here. I thought two sets being equipotent was equivalent to saying there was a bijection between them, but I thought when we were assuming here that all sets were measurable that implied that there was no bijection (by the quoted theorem) between $\mathbb{R}$ and $[\mathbb{R}]^\omega$ (and hence the size of the latter set is strictly greater than that of the former). Is there another meaning of equipotent that I've missed?

Comment: @Anon $[\mathbb R]^\omega\ne\mathbb R^\omega$

Comment: @bof My mistake again, I shouldn't have commented so quickly. Thank you. That answers my second question. Now the only other thing is to find the source of that theorem.

Comment: @Anon: I've added a link to an old MO question by yours truly.